# Memory Leak in Ctypes method

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, ctypes

I have a project mostly written in Python. This project runs on my Raspberry Pi (Model B). With the use of the Pi Camera I record to a stream. Every second I pauze the recording to take the last frame from the stream and compare it with a older frame. The comparing is done in C code (mainly because it is faster than Python).

The C code is called from Python using Ctypes. See the code below.

```
# Load picturecomparer.so and set argument and return types
cmethod = ctypes.CDLL(Paths.CMODULE_LOCATION)
cmethod.compare_pictures.restype = ctypes.c_double
cmethod.compare_pictures.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, types.c_char_p]
```

The 2 images that must be compared are stored on the disk. Python gives the paths of both images as arguments to the C code. The C code will return a value (double) which is the difference in percentage of both images.

```
# Call the C method to compare the images
difflevel = cmethod.compare_pictures(path1, path2)
```

The C code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
    #define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
    #include "stb_image.h"

    #ifndef STBI_ASSERT
        #define STBI_ASSERT(x)
    #endif
#endif

#define COLOR_R 0
#define COLOR_G 1
#define COLOR_B 2
#define OFFSET 10

double compare_pictures(const char* path1, const char* path2);

double compare_pictures(const char* path1, const char* path2)
{
    double totalDiff = 0.0, value;
    unsigned int x, y;

    int width1, height1, comps1;
    unsigned char * image1 = stbi_load(path1, &width1, &height1, &comps1, 0);

    int width2, height2, comps2;
    unsigned char * image2 = stbi_load(path2, &width2, &height2, &comps2, 0);

    // Perform some checks to be sure images are valid
    if (image1 == NULL | image2 == NULL) { return 0; }
    if (width1 != width2 | height1 != height2) { return 0; }

    for (y = 0; y < height1; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < width1; x++)
        {
            // Calculate difference in RED 
            value = (int)image1[(x + y*width1) * comps1 + COLOR_R] - (int)image2[(x + y*width2) * comps2 + COLOR_R];
            if (value < OFFSET && value > (OFFSET * -1)) { value = 0; }
            totalDiff += fabs(value) / 255.0;

            // Calculate difference in GREEN 
            value = (int)image1[(x + y*width1) * comps1 + COLOR_G] - (int)image2[(x + y*width2) * comps2 + COLOR_G];
            if (value < OFFSET && value >(OFFSET * -1)) { value = 0; }
            totalDiff += fabs(value) / 255.0;

            // Calculate difference in BLUE
            value = (int)image1[(x + y*width1) * comps1 + COLOR_B] - (int)image2[(x + y*width2) * comps2 + COLOR_B];
            if (value < OFFSET && value >(OFFSET * -1)) { value = 0; }
            totalDiff += fabs(value) / 255.0;
        }
    }
    totalDiff = 100.0 * totalDiff / (double)(width1 * height1 * 3);
    return totalDiff;
}
```

The C code will be executed every ~2 seconds. I just noticed that there is a memory leak. After around 10 to 15 minutes my Raspberry Pi haves like 10MB ram left to use. A few minutes later it crashes and doesn't respond anymore.

I have done some checks to find out what causes this in my project. My entire project uses around 30-40MB ram if I disable the C code. This project is all my Raspberry Pi have to execute.

Model B: 512MB ram which shares between CPU and GPU.
GPU: 128MB (/boot/config.txt).
My Linux distro uses: ~60MB.

So I have ~300MB for my project.

Hope someone could point me where it goes wrong, or if I have to call GC myself, etc..

Thanks in advance.

*p.s. I know the image comparing is not the best way, but it works for me now.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the images are being returned as pointers to buffers `stbi_load` must be allocating space for them and you are not releasing this space before returning so the memory leak is not surprising.

Check for the documentation to see if there is a specific stpi_free function or try adding `free(image1); free(image2);` before the final return.

Having checked I can categorically say that you should be calling `STBI_FREE(image1); STBI_FREE(image2);` before returning.

Comment: I looked in the stb_image.h and there was a function stbi_image_free which frees the memory used by stbi_load. I am running my project now for 15 minutes, and so far only ~50 MB is used. It seems not to raise anymore. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I presumed that after the method returned the totalDiff value that all other variables would be "destroyed" by the GC automatically.

Comment: @LittleOne - Python garbage collects __python objects__ not C ones and C does not have a garbage collector on most systems.